# Add +/- button on decimal keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

I need a text entry with +/- button on decimal keyboard like below image. Can anyone advise me how to achieve this.

[image: Desire keyboard image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to add a `UIButton` over your keyboard and then link this button to your `UITextField`.
To access your keyboard view, you can do as follows :

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
```

That's not a very clean solution though.

**Edit :**
Here is an example given by iGW ( he adds a done button to his keyboard ) :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25971206/3844377

Comment: Can you be specific little more?

Comment: I just edited my question, I found a link where someone added a "done" button to the keyboard.