# Get UIKeyboardFrame height at any moment

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, keyboard, ios11

I have an UIViewController that listen UIKeyboardWillShow and UIKeyboardWillHide to update a constraint according to the current keyboard state. The observers are perfectly called when my keyboard change, but if the keyboard is already opened in the previous UIViewController, my keyboardWillShow function isn't called : because the keyboard is already open, I think it's logic.

I want to get the keyboard height without hiding and showing keyboard between the controllers transition, but I didn't find any method available in Apple doc...

Any idea ?

Comment: You can't add UIKeyboardWillShow, UIKeyboardWillHide to the previous UIViewController?

Comment: And communicate the keyboard height value to the new UIViewController ? Yes, but I'm curious to know if a cleaner alternative exist ... I'd rather not add observer in all my controllers just for that.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352406/ios-get-keyboard-window

Comment: Ok, it look like tricky but why not :) Thanks